# Set Javascript height in document instead of external script

Tags: javascript, variables

I have an external Javascript file that enables a popup within a webpage. I would like to use the script to have multiple popups with different heights, but the height is set in the external file. So here's the relevant Javascript:

```
myHeight = ((y/2)-(400/2)); //400 is popup height
popup.style.top = (myHeight + bdy_ref.scrollTop) + 'px';
}

function popup(windowname) {
toggle('blanket');
toggle(windowname);
blanket_size(windowname);
}
```

And here's the link that calls in the webpage:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="popup('popup');">Click here</a>
```

So my question is, if I can set the windowname in the webpage, can I also set myHeight in the webpage, so I can have multiple popups with multiple heights while keeping just the one script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.resizeTo) [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeBy) to resize the window, but they can be disabled in the browser's configuration (at least in Firefox).

Comment: the problem is because he/she did not set window size for each window.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass your popup window size to popup function :

```
function popup(windowname, width, height) {
   //set the size here
   toggle('blanket');
   toggle(windowname);
   blanket_size(windowname);
}
```

in this way you can set window size for each window.

**Note**
Your javascript code should create different instances of window for each function call, unless you can not do this.

**Edited due to your comment**
You can not do it without editing your external js file (a bit)

but the easier way can be like this :

```
//not changed 
   function popup(windowname) {
       toggle('blanket');
       toggle(windowname);
       blanket_size(windowname);
    }

    function SetSize(width, height)
    {
       //set window size
    }
```

and call it like this :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="SetSize(400,500);popup('popup');">Click here</a>
```

in this way you need to add just one function called SetSize to your js without editing its other codes. a function witch just sets width and height variable.

Comment: Thanks, Farzin, but your code is in the external file that I don't want to edit. The variable code is this: <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="popup('popup');">Click here</a> So in my original post, I need to put the 400 somewhere in there and set up the Javascript appropriately.